# PyInstaller: “ImportError: No module named htmlentitydefs”

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I made the executable with pyinstaller like this (no --onefile or other options)

```
> pyinstaller brdg2.py
```

When i run it, [here's what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejUVA.png)
(screenshot of the command prompt before it closed).

From other threads, the warning at the start seem to be ignorable, so the problem would be

```
ImportError: No module named htmlentitydefs
```

**Edit:** I get [the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFiL6.png) *ImportError* with an .exe created with cx_freeze, so it doesn't seem related to the packaging programm.

Also to add some information i had just reinstalled Python and the necessary modules, and i didn't get this error when doing the same operations before (i did get other errors though).

Comment: Does PyInstaller work when running with `--onefile`?

Answer (score 3):

The htmlentitydefs module has been renamed to html.entities in Python 3. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

Use `html.entities` instead of `htmlentitydefs`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.entities.html